# What exactly happens in this example

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, dask, dask-dataframe

I am writing TPC-H query 6 in `dask` on a slice of the tpc-h dataset:

```py
start = time.time()
lineitem = dd.read_csv("s3://tpc-h-csv/lineitem/lineitem.tbl.1",sep="|", header = 0)
df = lineitem.rename(columns=dict(zip(lineitem.columns, lineitem_scheme)))
filtered_df = df.loc[(df.l_shipdate > "1994-01-01") & (df.l_discount >= 0.05) & (df.l_discount <= 0.07) & (df.l_quantity < 24)]
filtered_df['product'] = filtered_df.l_extendedprice * filtered_df.l_discount
print(filtered_df.product.sum().compute())
print(time.time() - start)
```

I have a couple questions:

1. Is this the fastest way to write said query in `Dask`?
2. The data that I am downloading from `S3` is 48GB. The memory on my node is 16 GB. Does `Dask` do batched computation? Does it persist to disk and then read from disk? What happens?

Comment: What happens is that your process will slow to a crawl as you thrash between your in memory data and swapping to the swap file.  No one will be happy.

Comment: This is not true. It makes significant use of disk. In fact memory usage never goes above 20%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, that seems like an efficient way to write the query in Dask, though it is hard to test given that the s3 bucket is not public. None of your operations require shuffling, so they should all be fairly inexpensive. For the second question, the answer is essentially yes, since the dataset you're downloading is larger than the memory available, Dask will spill to disk. Fine tuning how Dask manages memory is a bit tricky, there's more on that [here](http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html#memory-management) if you're interested.